# Does Dreamweaver CS 5.5 Hang for anybody else for very long periods of time?

Tags: dreamweaver

Every day, I load up Dreamweaver and it takes anywhere from 5-10 minutes to get going (sometimes if at all). I have tried the following steps:

- Uninstalled and reinstalled the software
- repaired windows registry using Free Windows Registry Repair
- uninstalled, run registry repair, reinstalled, run repair
- modified registry for Dreamweaver cs 5.5 and added the ResolveRemoteURLtoIPAddress to False

Nothing seems to be working. Has anybody else had this issue? I can't seem to find much information online about it and if I do, it is Mac related.

Note: I have other Adobe products installed as well (Reader X and Fireworks CS 5) if this helps with any troubleshooting.

### Update

I also just tried the following:
 - Remove all Adobe products
 - restarted machine
 - run registry cleaner
 - restarted machine
 - ran [Adobe Creative Suite Cleaner](http://www.adobe.com/support/contact/cscleanertool.html)
 - restarted machine
 - run registry cleaner
 - restart machine

still no luck and I'm waiting 6+ minutes for this program to load.

### Update 2

Just wiped CS 5.5 and installed CS6 trial to test - I am running into the same issues. No idea what is going wrong here now.

I have this on a i7 8gb machine as well so system resources are plenty.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a bucket load of fonts I believe Dreamweaver attempts to load them all in, it might also be trying to load in the last project, if so this could take a while depending on the size of the project.

Comment: no big font list here and no projects tied to the program. I have completely wiped out all Adobe related files and even tried reinstalling with the same results. I even used the Adobe Creative Suite Cleaner Tool as well. Just had another re installation with same results.